# Why do I receive an error when running Python code in cmd prmpt using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

How can Tensorflow have no "div" attribute? When I try to run a python  program from the command prompt (from tensorflow for dummies page 23 (simple program) I receive this error:

```
C:\Users\ME\TENSORFLOW\ch3>python simple_math.py
2020-04-26 13:50:29.871436: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-04-26 13:50:29.880652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-04-26 13:50:32.204590: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-04-26 13:50:32.212936: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-04-26 13:50:32.228615: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-C7DH370
2020-04-26 13:50:32.236344: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-C7DH370
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_math.py", line 13, in <module>
    quot = tf.div(const_a, const_b)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'div'
```

Did I install a wrong version of python? I installed python 3.7. Or perhaps I did not install tensorflow correctly. The book tensorflow for dummies was published in 2018. Maybe it was intended for another version of python? and/or another version of tensorflow? thank you so much in advance

Here is the code of the "simple.math.py" :

```
''' Perform simple math operations with TensorFlow '''

    from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function

    import tensorflow as tf

    # Math with constant tensors
    const_a = tf.constant(3.6)
    const_b = tf.constant(1.2)
    total = const_a + const_b
    quot = tf.div(const_a, const_b)

    # Math with random tensors
    rand_a = tf.random_normal([3], 2.0)
    rand_b = tf.random_uniform([3], 1.0, 4.0)
    diff = tf.subtract(rand_a, rand_b)

    # Vector multiplication
    vec_a = tf.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 4)
    vec_b = tf.fill([4, 1], 2.0)
    prod = tf.multiply(vec_a, vec_b)
    dot = tf.tensordot(vec_a, vec_b, 1)

    # Matrix multiplication
    mat_a = tf.constant([[2, 3], [1, 2], [4, 5]])
    mat_b = tf.constant([[6, 4, 1], [3, 7, 2]])
    mat_prod = tf.matmul(mat_a, mat_b)

   # Execute the operations
      with tf.Session() as sess:
        print('Sum: %f' % sess.run(total))
        print('Quotient: %f' % sess.run(quot))
        print('Difference: ', sess.run(diff))
        print('Element-wise product: ', sess.run(prod))
        print('Dot product: ', sess.run(dot))
        print('Matrix product: ', sess.run(mat_prod))


   thank you



After running the following program on windows with latest tensorflow 
installed, I receive the message underneath the python code below:

''' A simple TensorFlow application '''

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

# Create tensor
msg = tf.strings.join(['Hello ', 'TensorFlow!'])

# Launch session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(msg))



(venv) C:\Users\ME\TENSORFLOW\ch2>python hello_tensorflow.py
2020-04-29 00:28:30.676246: W 

tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load 
dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
    2020-04-29 00:28:30.684568: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart 
dlerror 
if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
    2020-04-29 00:28:32.573201: W 
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not 
load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
    2020-04-29 00:28:32.580400: E 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: 
UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
    2020-04-29 00:28:32.591791: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA 
diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-C7DH370
    2020-04-29 00:28:32.599756: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: 
DESKTOP- 
C7DH370
    2020-04-29 00:28:32.615405: I 
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1e0678689e0 
initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be 
used). 
Devices:
    2020-04-29 00:28:32.623598: I 
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device 
(0): 
Host, Default Version
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "hello_tensorflow.py", line 13, in <module>
        with tf.Session() as sess:
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

Comment: Hello Steven. Please post your code as we will not go to the book reference and find your program.

Comment: Can you add your tensorflow version and python version. I ran your code with no errors.

Comment: python 3.6.4  and tensorflow was installed  with the command "pip3 install tensorflow"  I'm not sure I am installing it correctly. Do I change directories in the command prompt to where python is installed and then enter "pip3 install tensorflow" ? Thank you

Comment: Changing the directories will not matter. Check my answer and please comment if you have a question. otherwise if it helped you mark it as accepted so you can help others.

Comment: I am on the official tensorflow site and I am following the directions. I downloaded   pyhon 3.8 and checked all boxes, I installed  Microsoft Visual C++. long paths are enabled    When I come up to the step of entering "pip3 install -U pip virtualenv" on the command line, I receive the folowing error: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: start CMD with administrator privileges. so search cmd on start menu, right click on command prompt and run as administrator

Comment: Thank you forthelulx  but After using CMD as admin, it appears to be installed but I get the following error after rinning the simple program above. :                                                                         
                File "hello_tensorflow.py", line 13, in <module>
        with tf.Session() as sess:
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: TensorFlow 2. I followed the directions here:https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: I really suspect that your tensorflow for dummies book is using the 1.X api. It could even be the case that your first error with the tensorflow.div missing was because your book is **really** old and using old 1.x api. I think you'll find divide in recent 1.15 api.

Comment: If it is [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TensorFlow-Dummies-Matthew-Scarpino/dp/1119466210) just throw that away. I looked at the excerpt available on Amazon, it starts off with some wrong claims, and doesn't show the details to create an environment that works. The tensorflow api moves incredibly fast. You could do the examples if it said which version to install at least. Some of the blame falls on google too.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is there any command I can enter to see if tensorflow is actually installed on my computer? I tried "import tensorflow as tf" and I got this error: >>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-04-30 02:09:31.565023: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-04-30 02:09:31.574991: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>>>

Comment: Do you have CUDA? It looks like you need CUDA 10.1.

Comment: Or, if you don't have an nvidia gpu you can ignore that from the description. If you want to check if you have a working tensorflow installation. Try one of their up-to-date examples. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

Comment: Or something like this for just making a model without running it. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview

Comment: thanks everyone. Just got in contact with the author. He said the book is outdated so I will close the thread thanks to everyone. Not sure how I close the thread though

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow 2.x working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Math with constant tensors
const_a = tf.constant(3.6)
const_b = tf.constant(1.2)
total = const_a + const_b
quot = tf.divide(const_a, const_b)
print(quot)

# Math with random tensors
rand_a = tf.random_normal([3], 2.0)
rand_b = tf.random_uniform([3], 1.0, 4.0)
diff = tf.subtract(rand_a, rand_b)
print(diff)

# Vector multiplication
vec_a = tf.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 4)
vec_b = tf.fill([4, 1], 2.0)
prod = tf.multiply(vec_a, vec_b)
dot = tf.tensordot(vec_a, vec_b, 1)
print(dot)

# Matrix multiplication
mat_a = tf.constant([[2, 3], [1, 2], [4, 5]])
mat_b = tf.constant([[6, 4, 1], [3, 7, 2]])
mat_prod = tf.matmul(mat_a, mat_b)
print(mat_prod)
```

**Output**

```
Tensor("truediv_3:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Sub_4:0", shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Tensordot_4:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Tensor("MatMul_4:0", shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32)
```